# Unable to close the new graph window without closing the main window

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on a project of visualization of OS Job Scheduling Algorithms in **Python with GUI library - PyQt5**.
Clicking the generate graph button, I want to display a graph in a new window.
I have made an attempt to implement but the **problem is the I am not able to close new window in which graph is displayed without closing the main window**.
Below is the code I implemented.

The main program file - **ProcessScheduler.py**

`

```
# importing required libs

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    # declaring global variables

    # Importing all the functions from other modules
    from src.Buttons.Plot import graphBtnHandler
    
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        MainWindow.resize(1280, 687)
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(1280, 687)
        # GUI setup
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate(
            "MainWindow", "Process Scheduler"))
        # GUI setup    
        # Adding Handler on Generate Graph button.
        self.GraphBtn.clicked.connect(self.graphBtnHandler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle(QtWidgets.QStyleFactory.create('Fusion'))
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`

```
**Plot.py** - where the graph plot code is written
```

`

```
# importing required libs

def graphBtnHandler(self):

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    # setting up the graph ploting details
    
    plt.show(block=False)
```

`

Here are the pics for the application main window and the graph window.

1. Main Window:
   [image: Main Window]
2. Graph Window:
   [image: Graph Window]

You can see in the Graph Window that the close button is disabled. It gets enable only after closing the main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the [windowModality](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#windowModality-prop) of the window to `ApplicationModal`, which means that it will be blocking any interaction with *any other* widget/window until it's closed.

The simple solution is to remove that line from your code.

If you used Designer, instead, the *right* solution is to open the ui file in Designer, unset that property, save the file, recreate the ui file with pyuic and **never modify it again**, but use it as a module as suggested in the official documentation about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html). Files created with pyuic should **never** be modified (nor you should ever try to mimic their behavior).

Besides that, importing a function within a class to use it as an instance method is not a good approach.

Comment: Thanks! commenting the line worked. Yeah I have used designer for designing the GUI and as there are many algorithms and functionalities to be implemented, putting everything in a single file was making it hard to debug so I made modules and imported the functions within a class. Anyways, I'm very much thankful for the solution and your advices.

Comment: Separating the programming from the ui creation is a good idea, and that's just one of the many good reason for which the pyuic files should *never* be modified once created, besides being rewritten when the ui requires modifications. Besides that, using a single file is not necessarily a bad thing: if you find troubles debugging, remember that IDEs often cut out many important debug information, and running the code from a shell/prompt is always helpful. Finally, while ui/logic separation is good, it should be done in the right way, and that's **not** by importing methods inside the class.